# server requirements for social network sites

Tags: networking, web, webserver, server, social-media

I am developing a social media network and I decided to host it in better web service provider's VPS server at the start up stage. 
But, I have 1Gbps fiber optic internet line (optional static IP) at my home. Is it enough for this site and how many concurrent users can access this site via 1Gbps fiber connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's depend on your server structure and file sizes. I think you can get an idea by this calculation.

Suppose that your web site has one file and size is 200kb.

Theoretically;

```
Monthly bandwidth = ((1000Gbps/8)MB * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30) = 324000000MB

Monthly pages     = (324000000)MB / (200/1024)MB = 1658880000
Daily pages       = 1658880000/30                = 55296000
Pages per hour    = 55296000/24                  = 2304000
pages per minute  = 2304000/60                   = 38400
pages per second  = 38400/60                     = 640
```

But in practically less than this.